# Can somemone explain why my footer content isnt wrapping into two columns?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my footer. I set up the footer to be a flexbox and I want the "social media" header and icons to wrap onto the second row of the footer but for some reason whenever I set the "container" class to `flex-wrap: wrap`everything in the footer becomes aligned vertically down the screen.

```css
       .container {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-items: baseline;
            background: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;


        }

       

        .items {
            background: transparent;
            order: 5;
            flex: 1 auto;
            color: white;
            padding: 40px 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;

        }

        .items a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #a2a4a7;

        }

        .items a:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: white;
        }


        #footer-headings {
            font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
        }



        .fa-facebook {
            background: #3B5998;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 50px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;

        }

        .fa-twitter {
            background: #55ACEE;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 50px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;

        }

        .fa-instagram {
            background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 50px;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;

        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
            .fa-instagram {
                background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                width: 50px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 5px 2px;
                border-radius: 50%;

            }

            .fa-twitter {
                background: #55ACEE;
                color: white;
                font-size: 10px;
                width: 50px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 5px 2px;
                border-radius: 50%;

            }

            .fa-facebook {
                background: #3B5998;
                color: white;
                font-size: 10px;
                width: 50px;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 5px 2px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }


        .underline {
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .underline:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 0;
            right: 100%;
            bottom: -5px;
            background: white;
            height: 2.5px;
            transition-property: left right;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        }

        .underline:hover:after,
        .underline:focus:after,
        .underline:active:after {
            right: 0;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
            .items {
                font-size: 10px;

            }

            #footer-headings {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
            <div class="items">

                <p id="footer-headings">Useful Links</p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Find a Store</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Sign Up For Email</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Become A Member</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Site Feedback</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 25%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div> -->
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <strong>
                    <p id="footer-headings">About The
                        League</p><br>
                </strong>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">About Us</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Careers</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">News</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Sustainability</a></p>
            </div>


            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 50%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div> -->

            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p id="footer-headings">
                    <strong>Policies</strong></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Terms of service</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Refund</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Privacy</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Shipping</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 75%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto;  ">

            </div> -->
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p id="footer-headings">Need To Talk?</p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Order Status</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Returns</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Payment Options</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Contact Us</a></p><br>
            </div>
            <div class="items wrap">
                <h3 id="footer-headings">Follow Us!</h3><br>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Any help with getting the "Follow Us" and the social icons belew it to wrap onto the next row and remain horizontal and ideally centered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you should use **flex-wrap:wrap** inside the container, but also remove **width:100%** from items.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: baseline;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;


}

.full {
  /* flex-grow: -1; */
}





.items {
  background: transparent;
  order: 5;
  flex: 1 auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a2a4a7;

}

.items a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}


#footer-headings {
  font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}



.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.fa-instagram {
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .fa-instagram {
    background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;

  }

  .fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;

  }

  .fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}


.underline {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: white;
  height: 2.5px;
  transition-property: left right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underline:hover:after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  right: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .items {
    font-size: 10px;

  }

  #footer-headings {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
            <div class="items">

                <p id="footer-headings">Useful Links</p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Find a Store</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Sign Up For Email</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Become A Member</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Site Feedback</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 25%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div> -->
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <strong>
                    <p id="footer-headings">About The
                        League</p><br>
                </strong>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">About Us</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Careers</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">News</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Sustainability</a></p>
            </div>


            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 50%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div> -->

            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p id="footer-headings">
                    <strong>Policies</strong></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Terms of service</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Refund</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Privacy</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Shipping</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 75%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto;  ">

            </div> -->
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p id="footer-headings">Need To Talk?</p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Order Status</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Returns</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Payment Options</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#" class="underline">Contact Us</a></p><br>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="items  wrap full">
                <h3 id="footer-headings">Follow Us!</h3><br>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            </div>


        </div>
```